# How to text wrap headers/questions in NewForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-on-prem, newform

Does anyone know of a way in SharePoint 2013 (on premise) to text wrap the column headers/questions in NewForm.aspx. Currently I have long column headers so when you select 'new item' on the list the headers which appear down the left (which im using as questions) are really long creating an ugly and not friendly horizontal scroll.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to override the `white-space`-property within the `nobr` element which is the one where the text is located. Then you can define the standard width for your column titles on `.ms-formlabel`.

```
.ms-formlabel {
    width: 400px;
}
.ms-formlabel nobr {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Add the CSS either in the style sheet referenced in your master page, or to the list's NewForm.aspx into a web part.

Comment: Why `!important` ? Seems to work without...

Comment: @Nils yeah, you are right. `white-space` was only defined within corev15's .css and not in the DOM as I at first had thought for some reason. Fixing.

Comment: Thanks guys, I put the code into a script editor webpart and it worked a treat!

Comment: For anyone not very script/code minded it needed the style tags to work forme.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             <style type= "text/css"> 

.ms-formlabel {
    width: 400px;
}
.ms-formlabel nobr {
    white-space: normal;
}

</style>